# Ruby String Formatting: Omit element in list

Tags: ruby, string-formatting

Ruby lets me do:

```
    list = [1,2,3]
    puts "%s %s" % list
```

and returns `1 2`.  What if I want to skip the second element (to print `1 3`)?  Yes I know it's easily doable without string formatting, but for my specific case I want to know if it's possible using string formatting.

Comment: You could write `puts "%s %c%s" % [1,2,3] #=> "1 3"`, just don't expect it to always work. If fact, it doesn't even work here. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
puts "%1$s %3$s" % list
```

........

Answer (score 1):

```
"%s %0.s%s" % [1,2,3]
  #=> "1 3"
```

The decimal point tells Ruby that `0` is the field width rather than a flag. You could also write `%0.0s`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
list = [1,2,3]
puts "%s %s" % list.values_at(0,2)
```